# Upload toDataUrl image through jquery

Tags: php, jquery, canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying to create an image out of my canvas, but i can't seem to get a working uploaded PNG on the backend after some tries. Could someone look at what's going on here?

My javascript:

```
    stage.toDataURL({
    callback: function(dataUrl) {
        var imgURL = dataUrl; // keep the entire url
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.xxxx.nl/pointer/upload.php", 
            data: ({imgData : imgURL}),
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                //window.open(dataUrl); // Show result stage in a new window
                alert(result); // show php error if exists
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And my really basic .php for now:

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng($_POST['imgData']);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

My error log:

```
[Fri Mar 08 11:29:16 2013] [error] [client 24.132.214.139] mod_security: Access denied with code 500. Error reading request body, error code 70007: The timeout specified has expired [hostname "www.ccc.nl"] [uri "/pointer/upload.php"]
```

Comment: Your JavaScript code is perfectly fine. On the PHP side, you may just use [PHP-FileUpload](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload) which comes with [`DataUriUpload`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/blob/023f812226673ac9e0696d8a3579bb7380606dda/src/DataUriUpload.php). It’s documented [here](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/tree/023f812226673ac9e0696d8a3579bb7380606dda#data-uri-uploads). Alternatively, you may look up its source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
var canvasData = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

You get the base64 encoded string representing the .png, like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAAEsCAYAAAB5fY51AAAGB………
```

Notice this string is prefixed with this header: data:image/png;base64.  This header is un-needed/un-recognized by a .png file—and fouls up imagecreatefrompng().  So, when saving this string to create a .png, you must strip off the header.  On the php side you can do it like this (although you could alternatively strip it off on the client-side):

```
$justPngData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);
```

And then continue normally…